# Cannot inherit tkinter classes

Tags: python, tkinter

Based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769306) from my previous question, I am trying to inherit the `tkinter` (`ttkbootstrap` to be precise) classes in this manner:

```py
class _TrWidget:
    def __init__(
        self, type_: Type[ttk.Widget], master: ttk.Widget, text: str, **kwargs
    ):
        type_(master, text=_tr(text), **kwargs)


class _TrButton(_TrWidget, ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master: ttk.Widget = None, text: str = "", **kwargs):
        _TrWidget(ttk.Button, master, text, **kwargs)
```

gives me the error:

> AttributeError: '_TrButton' object has no attribute 'tk'

*when I do:*

```py
button = _TrButton(master, "Button").pack()
```

Now this might be completely unrelated to `tkinter` itself, since I haven't used this particular type of inheritance anywhere else.

Comment: Your two constructors never call parent constructors. They allocate random objects and discard them immediately. Go re-read that answer you linked; it'll show you how to use `super` in Python.

Comment: Why are you using this type of inheritance rather than the method shown in the other answer?

Comment: @BryanOakley You told me how to implement it for a button, but I want to use it for all types of widgets

Comment: I showed how to do it for a button because that's what you used for your question. You can inherit from any widget you want.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class _TrWidget(ttk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master: ttk.Widget, text: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, text=_tr(text), **kwargs)


class _TrButton(_TrWidget, ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master: ttk.Widget = None, text: str = "", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, text, **kwargs)
```

I don't even know how that worked but it did